# If $f(x) \le M$ and $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = A$, prove that $A \le M$.

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

I am an adult software developer who is trying to do a math reboot. I am working through the exercises in the following book.

Ayres, Frank , Jr. and Elliott Mendelson. 2013. *Schaum's Outlines Calculus Sixth Edition (1,105 fully solved problems, 30 problem-solving videos online)*. New York: McGraw Hill. ISBN 978-0-07-179553-1.

Writing proofs is not yet intuitive for me and I would like to know if my proof for the following problem is complete or if I skipped steps.  I have reviewed the following document about writing proofs.

Cheng, Eugenia. 2004. "How to write proofs: a quick guide." University of Chicago. Last modified October. http://cheng.staff.shef.ac.uk/proofguide/proofguide.pdf.

**Chapter 7 Limits, problem 26.**

Prove: If $f(x) \le M$ for all $x$ in an open interval containing $a$ and if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = A$, then $A \le M$.
(*Hint:* Assume $A>M$. Choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}(A-M)$ and derive a contradiction.)

**My understanding.**

The key to this proof is whether or not $A>M$ or $A \le M$.  I do not see how the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in the hint helps.

**My proof.**

Let $f(x) \le M$ for $x \in (a-Q, a+Q)$ where $0 < Q$.
Let $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = A$. For any $0 < \epsilon$ there exists $0<\delta$ such that $|x-a| < \delta$.

Suppose $\epsilon = A - M$, which implies $M < A$ because $0<\delta$.
$$
|f(x) - A| < \epsilon \\
-\epsilon < f(x) - A < \epsilon \\
-(A - M) < f(x) - A < A - M \\
M - A < f(x) - A < A - M \\
M < f(x) < 2A - M \ \ {\Large \#} \\
$$
By definition $f(x) \le M$, so $\epsilon$ can not possibly have a value that implies $M < A$.  Therefore, $A \le M$. $\square$

Comment: The factor of a half is unnecessary.

Comment: This is a bit awkaward in terms of redaction, but it's the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, kudos on doing a math reboot.  Learning to write proofs, especially if you're doing it without benefit of a teacher, ain't easy; it takes time, patience, and practice.  I take it as a good sign that you question the helpfulness of the $1\over2$ in the hint. It shows you're thinking for yourself.

The ideas in your proof are basically correct, but the proof itself will benefit from a rewrite, to express the ideas accurately and clearly.  So let me be a bit picky.

There are two key problems with the presentation of ideas. One, after a pair of "let" statements which basically express the given assumptions of the problem, there is the stand-alone sentence "For any $0\lt\epsilon$ there exists $0\lt\delta$ such that $|a-x|\lt\delta$." As is, this sentence doesn't really say much of anything, since the choice $\delta=Q$ works for all $x\in(a-Q,a+Q)$. What's needed here is a *continuation* of the sentence that connects back to the $\epsilon$:

> For any $0\lt\epsilon$ there exists $0\lt\delta$ such that
>   $|a-x|\lt\delta$ implies $|f(x)-A|\lt\epsilon$.

That is, some steps in some proofs boil down to simply stating a definition, in this case the definition of limit. Note, however, that even this isn't quite correct.  What the sentence should *really* say, in order to be fully logically correct, is

> For any $0\lt\epsilon$ there exists $0\lt\delta$ such that
>   $0\lt|a-x|\lt\delta$ implies $|f(x)-A|\lt\epsilon$.

I'll leave it to you to spot what I added there, and to think about why it's important. (Hint: The word "continuous" is nowhere among the assumptions about the function $f$.)

The second key problem is in the next stand-alone sentence, "Suppose $\epsilon=A-M$, which implies $M\lt A$ because $0\lt\delta$." The logic, as it's expressed here, is all backwards.  There is no $\delta$ until you've chosen an $\epsilon$, and you have to choose an $\epsilon$ that you already know (or *suppose*) to be positive, not argue that a choice you've made *has to be* positive simply because you've called it $\epsilon$ and therefore need for it to be positive.  Instead, you want to say something like this:

> Suppose $M\lt A$. Then, if we let $\epsilon=A-M$, we have
>   $0\lt\epsilon$, in which case there exists $0\lt\delta$ such that
>   $$\begin{align}0\lt|x-a|\lt\delta&\implies|f(x)-A|\lt\epsilon\\&\implies|f(x)-A|\lt
>  A-M\\ &\implies-(A-M)\lt f(x)-A\lt A-M\\ &\implies etc. \end{align}$$

(Note, I have a stylistic preference for showing explicit implication arrows, rather than simply writing down a list of seemingly disconnected statements.)

I hope this helps.  Again, it takes time, patience and practice to learn how to marshal your thoughts into a good, clean, well written mathematical prose. But it looks to me like you're off to a good start. Keep at it!

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct, however quite twisted. You shouldn't say "suppose $\epsilon=A-M $". You better go the other way around. I would suggest to go this way: Suppose to the contrary that $A>M $. So we can choose $\epsilon=A-M $, and since this specific  $\epsilon $ is positive,  we would get (by your calculation) $$f (x)>M $$ for some $x $ in the interval, different than $a $. This is a contradiction, and thus the assumption is wrong. That is, $A\not >M $, so $A\leq M $.

Answer (score 1):

When presenting this proof we usually use the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ to make it very clear that $f(x) \geq M + \varepsilon / 2 > M$, and not have to bother with strict inequalities. For instance sometimes in defining the continuity of $f$ at point $a$ you could end your sentence by using a large inequality, those two definitons would be equivalent. It's actually a good exercice to proove it. But then if you use a large inequality to define the continuity at point $a$ you *have to* use $\varepsilon = (A - M)/2$ in this proof, otherwise your last inequality would be $ M \leq f(x)$ which is not in contradiction with $f(x) \leq M$. I don't know if I made my point clear, but that's reason behind this hint in your book. ;)

Another remark, you should not say $0<Q$ but rather $Q>0$ (easier to read). On this point it might be just a personnal preference though...

Comment: I agree, if you read "Choose $\epsilon\gt0$" as "Choose an $\epsilon$ that is greater than $0$" then it's tempting to read "Choose $0\lt\epsilon$" as "Choose a $0$ that is less than $\epsilon$," which sounds weird. On the other hand, since our convention for the number line has smaller stuff to the left of bigger stuff, it can be cognitively easier to keep things straighten when inequalities are ordered in the same direction. So my personal preference is to mostly use "$\lt$."

Comment: I am a programmer and Code Complete by Steve McConnell convinced me to use only $<$ and $\le$.  The logic is to keep smaller things on the left.  This arguably makes it easier to reason about complex logic.  For example, $(b \le 0) \lor ((0 \le a) \land (a < b) \land (b < c))$.  I realize math is not programming.

Comment: As you said, from a programming point of view it might be right (or at least more sensitive) to use only $<$ and $\leq$. But the reason why I'd rather write $\varepsilon > 0$ is I always have the logical phrase $\forall \varepsilon \in (0, +\infty)$... I always find it very, _very_ ugly to write $\forall 0 < t$ for instance, for all what, 0? Hence my preference for $Q > 0$, but once again, it's just a matter of convenience, not that matters at all...